# Geolocate a batch of IP addresses

Tags: webapp-rec, geolocation

I'm looking for a website to localize IP addresses (at least country, town and ISP would be a plus) without limitation.

I would like to enter several address (as [this site](http://www.ip2location.com/free.asp) does) from browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the free Maxmind database's (both Country Lite and City Lite).  You can download them and set them up for free on your local server.  That way you can go to town and don't have to worry about any limits.

GeoLite Country:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry

GeoLite City:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

They also offer a free lookup on their site, as well as a free javascript based lookup, but they would both have some limits, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are going to struggle to find a free *and* unlimited service.

I would think that the lookup process is quite expensive either in terms of the processing and/or bandwidth required or these people get charged by their provider, so allowing anyone unlimited lookups would incur monetary penalties.

If you need more than 20 lookups per day then you should really look into paying for the service.